# If a finite set tiles the integers, must it be an arithmetic progression?

Tags: arithmetic, tiling, additive-combinatorics

Let $P$ be a finite subset of ${\mathbb Z}$ containing at least three elements. I say that $P$ tiles $\mathbb Z$ if $\mathbb Z$ can be written as a disjoint union of translates of $P$.

Trivially if $P$ is an arithmetic progression of the form $\lbrace t+sk \ | \ 1\leq k \leq M \rbrace$ where $s$ and $M$ are coprime, then $P$ tiles $\mathbb Z$ (because of Euclidean division and the Chinese remainder theorem).

Is the converse true ?

**My thoughts :** It is easy to see that $P=\lbrace 1,2,4\rbrace$ can never tile $\mathbb Z$. For suppose it did, and suppose $\bigcup_{t\in T}t+P$ is such a tiling. We call the $t+P$ (for $t\in T$) distinguished translates of $P$. Choose any $t_1\in T$. Then $t_1+3$ must be in some distinguished  translate of $P$, which can only be $(t_1+2)+P$ or $(t_1+1)+P$ or $(t_1-1)+P$. But all those intersect $t_1+P$, contradiction.

Comment: $$\{ 1,2,5,6\}$$ tiles $\Bbb Z$ and it's not an arithmetic progression.

Comment: There's a lot of literature on this, often relating to cyclotomic polynomials. You're asking for $P(x) \times T(x) = 1/(1-x)$, where  $P(x) \neq (1-x^{kn})/(1-x^n)$. There are solutions like $P(x) = (1+x)(1+x^4)$ in Crostul's example, giving $T(x) = 1/[ (1-x)(1+x)(1+x^4)]$ whose coefficients are 1 or 0.

Comment: @Crostul I apparently misinterpret "tiling $\mathbb Z$". How do we get the numbers of the form $6k+3$ and $6k+4$ this way ?

Comment: @Peter $\ldots, \{1,2,5,6\}, \{3,4,7,8\},\{9,10,13,14\},\{11,12,15,16\},\ldots$.

Comment: @Milten Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @CalvinLin That viewpoint corresponds at first glance to tiling $\mathbb N$. Does it work in general for tiling $\mathbb Z$ too?

Comment: @CalvinLin You might also give some google keywords so that others can find the literature on this.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for your feedback. Could you please elaborate on "a lot of literature" and indicate a few mainstream references for ignoramuses like me.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Search for "Tiling the Integers" (which was the term that you used). There are several papers ([example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9802122.pdf) ) that use that term.

Comment: @Milten Essentially yes. In the linked paper above (which deals with $\mathbb{Z}$), see Lemma 1.2. Every tiling by translates of a finite set is periodic. Thus, dealing with $ \mathbb{Z}$ is the same as dealing with some $\mathbb{Z_n}$ which is the same as dealing with $ \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\{1;2;5;6 \}$$ tiles $\Bbb Z$ and is not an arithmetic progression.